# LuaBind bindings for c standard library?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I've begun running into slight issues with certain functions that I've bound to lua using luabind.  These functions return or take std:string objects as arguments, and the data that c++ eventually gets is garbage, apparently because lua doesn't recognize the datatype.  I'm fine with manually binding std:: classes over as I need them, but I have to wonder if that's already been done for the c standard library anywhere.  I can't seem to find any sort of bindings library; does anyone know if such a project exists?

Comment: Small point: std::string is not a part of the C standard library. It is a part of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luabind already has automatic conversions between Lua strings and std::string (as well as char*). So you should be able to use them as parameters and/or return values just fine. If you are unable to do so, then something is going wrong, either on your side or on Luabind's side.

Luabind also has [an adapter](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#return-stl-iterator) to convert a return type that conforms to an STL-style container into a Lua iterator function. Thus, you can use it in a for-loop like this:

```
for object in CppFuncThatReturnsStdVector() do
    --Do something with "object"
end
```

Other than these, I am not aware of any particular effort to make a Luabind library that directly exposes the standard C++ library to Lua. It probably wouldn't be a good idea anyway; Lua tables cover most of the needs you might have for STL-style containers. And most of the other stuff are things Lua can handle with its own standard library.

Comment: I see.  I wasn't necessarily interested in binding the _functionality_, per se, just on exposing those types as recognizable to Lua.  Thanks for the speedy reply.